# Magento 2.2: How to disable Attribute Set on product page

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, attribute-set

I have about 5000 types of attributes and when loading the product page it stays locked for 20 seconds.

How can I remove this field from the product page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to remove "More Information" attribute tab in product details page.

Go to catalog_product_view.xml in your theme. As per below path:
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Add this line in your catalog_product_view.xml.

<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true"/>
</body>

Hope this helps!
```